# How to change the Logging Level of a service using the log4net.config file ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net

I know there are several other similar questions and answers but they don't work in my scenario.

My application gets the path to a log4net.config file inside a folder which I provide as a parameter. Once the exact path is acquired. I initialize my XmlConfigurator as such:

```
 XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(configFilePath));
```

Then, I receive the current logging level using the following code

```
string currentLevel = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level.ToString();
```

which retrieves the correct current log level for me from that file (I do this to check whether the Configurator is linking to the file and working properly).

The value I am retrieving from the previous line of code is the very level I need to change. For this, I use the following code, proposed as solutions for other similar questions:

```
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level = newLevel;
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).RaiseConfigurationChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
```

where newLevel is the variable storing the level I want to change it to, e.g.

`newLevel = Level.Fatal;`

After a lot of debugging, I realized that if I receive the current level again after the previous code using the same

```
string currentLevel = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level.ToString();
```

statement again, it does in fact give me the newly set value of the logging level.

However, some why, there are no changes made to the actual config file when I open and view it in a text editor. Also, once I restart my application, or if I write another XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch (exactly the same as before) statement before checking the newly set log level, the log level shows as if it is unchanged.

Please help me sort out my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: From my knowledge, log4net does not store configuration changes into the config file. This is because the file can be in the (read-only) program file directory etc. It only configures itself from such a file. If you want to change the file, use the known .NET XML reader and writer classes.

Comment: @KBO Will using .net xml reader and writer classes allow me to change the log level of the 'service' at runtime or will I have to restart the service for the changes to take affect ? 
I was preferring the '.raiseConfigurationChanged' solution as I read it allows me to change the log level while the application is running.

Comment: Your application/service shouldn't care about the output logging level, beyond what is available to it (read only) in log4net types. Your app just logs, deciding the level of each event at the time. People/actions _external_ to your app - e.g. administrators, someone debugging an issue, etc - decide the output logging level (sure, a developer of the app will typically set the default/initial level). Modifications to that by the app itself do not make sense in the nicely separated-concerns model log4net gives you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change configuration in your program, it is not reflected in the configuration file. If your application is monitoring your configuration, you can change the log level by editing the configuration file directly. It will be picked up by log4net.